# D3 Brush and Zoom in React

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

So I am trying to implement the ability to zoom in and use the brush feature included with D3 in the line graph I made in React using D3. I see many examples online that accomplish this in plain javascript. How would I do this in React?

The way I've been doing it is creating a node in the beginning of my code, appending all the D3 aspects of the graph to the node, and then reference node and define it's dimensions in the render() and return statements in the component the graph is in.

```
render()
{
    return(

        <svg style={{paddingTop: "25px"}}
        ref={node => this.node = node}
        width={this.state.svgWidth} height={this.state.svgHeight}>
        </svg>

    )
}
```

Here's an example of how I've been using D3 to render the x and y axis, and basic shapes:

```
var x = scaleBand()
        .domain(mainXAxisTextArray)
        .range([0, width])

var y = scaleLinear()
        .domain(yAxisArray)
        .range([height, 0])

var xAxis = select(node)
            .append('g')
            .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+(height + 15)+")")
            .style("font",".8em sans-serif")
            .call(axisBottom(x))
            .attr("id", "updateSize")
            .attr("class", 'xAxis')



var yAxis = select(node)
            .append('g')
            .attr("transform","translate("+margin.left+","+(margin.top)+")")
            .style("font",".8em sans-serif")
            .call(axisLeft(y).tickArguments([tickNum]).tickFormat(format("$,")))
            .attr("id", "updateSize")
            .attr('class', "yAxis")

let rect = select(node)
                .append("rect")
                .attr("width", rectWidth)
                .attr("height", height)
                .attr("y", margin.top)
                .attr("x", rectX)
                .attr("fill", "#d3d3d3")
                .attr("opacity", "0.2")
                .attr("id", "updateSize")
                .attr('class', 'forecastedSpendRectangle')
```

I've been specifically looking at this example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172

I want to be able to do this in the React component that this graph is in. Some differences between the graph I'm making and the linked example are that mine consists of a series of lines, dots, and text, as opposed to the example which has a path alone.

I realize I have to import the appropriate functions, but I am confused as to how I actually use them in React. I've done this with D3 select, but the brush and zoom functionality in React leaves me stumped